# FireDac TFDScript.ExecScript() not working

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have a TFDScript component loaded with 2 scripts.

In my code I am trying to execute a selected script using

```
TFDScript1.ExecuteScript('InsertScript');
```

but I get this error

```
[DCC Error] StartTask.pas(77): There is no overloaded version of 'ExecuteScript' that can be called with these arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.ExecuteScript), you're expected to pass in a `TStrings` instance, however you're trying to pass in just a `String`. You need to create a `TStringList` instance and pass it as the parameter instead. The particular error your are receiving indicates that you are passing parameters which differ from the parameters which are expected.

```
var
  Script: TStringList;
begin
  Script:= TStringList.Create;
  try
    Script.Text:= 'Some SQL Script';
    FDScript1.ExecuteScript(Script);
  finally
    Script.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you already have script loaded, then call [`ExecuteAll`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FireDAC.Comp.Script.TFDScript.ExecuteAll) instead.

If, for some reason, you wish to execute only one script at a time, then create multiple `TFDScript` instances. This component doesn't appear to be designed to run only one of the multiple scripts at a time.

Comment: Reading further it dosent do what I want. I want to execute the a sql script all ready loaded into the component. ie TFDScript.SqlScripts[2].Exec but it dosent seem to exist. unless some else has a solution

Comment: Then call `ExecuteAll`. You should read the documentation more carefully, I've never even used this component and I found your answer in seconds. Even the code completion would have given you your answer without the documentation at all.

Comment: ExecuteAll executes all the scripts. when I have a 3 queries (Insert, update, delete) loaded I only want to run one at a time.

Comment: @DanielRogers That wasn't a part of your question. I answered your question as it's currently written. Your question asked about an error you got while calling a particular procedure. That's precisely what I answered, plus more. If you have another question, then please ask another question.